# How to close dialog from withing onClickListener

Tags: android, button, dialog, onclick

I already have the `AlertDialog.Builder` set to `final`.

I have a button inside of the dialog box that when clicked, makes a purchase for the user and then closes. I'm having issues with the "closes" portion. Here's the code for the button:

```
    Button buyButton = new Button(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100, 0.0f);
    buyButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
    buyButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if (STOCK_TO_PURCHASE.size() != 0) {
                Player thisPlayer = players[getPlayerIndexByPlayOrder(CURRENT_TURN)];
                purchaseStock(thisPlayer);
                buyStockDialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                buyStockDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

The IDE is telling me I have to typecast `buyStockDialog`. If I typecast it though, I get a runtime error telling me I can't typecast `buyStockDialog` to `DialogInterface`.

What's the best way to handle this?

I already have a custom `onBackPressed` method and considered forcing the application to mimic the back button being pressed. What do you think the best solution here is?

Declaration line for AlertDialog.Builder as per request:

```
    ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme);
    final AlertDialog.Builder buyStockDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
    buyStockDialog.setTitle("Buy Stock: ");
```

As per Second request, the full Dialog's Code and Layout:

```
public void buyStock(View view){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme);
    final AlertDialog.Builder buyStockDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
    buyStockDialog.setTitle("Buy Stock: ");

    //create ScrollView to hold everything
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(context);

    //generate content for dialog       
    LinearLayout dialogContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
    dialogContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 350, 1);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    dialogContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
    dialogContainer.setPadding(15, 15, 0, 15);
    dialogContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    //each hotel stock options
    for (int i = 0; i < hotels.size(); i++) {
        Hotel testHotel = hotels.get(i);
        testHotel.setPrice(200);
        View stockPicker = getStockPicker(testHotel);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams pickerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 75, 1.0f);
        pickerParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        stockPicker.setLayoutParams(pickerParams);
        dialogContainer.addView(stockPicker);
        stockPicker.setBackgroundColor(0xffffff);
    }

    LinearLayout scrollWrapper = new LinearLayout(context);
    scrollWrapper.addView(scrollView);
    scrollWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 300, 1.0f));

    scrollView.addView(dialogContainer);
    scrollView.setLayoutParams(params);

    LinearLayout dialogLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    dialogLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    dialogLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    Button buyButton = new Button(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100, 0.0f);
    buyButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
    buyButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if (STOCK_TO_PURCHASE.size() != 0) {
                Player thisPlayer = players[getPlayerIndexByPlayOrder(CURRENT_TURN)];
                purchaseStock(thisPlayer);
                buyStockDialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                buyStockDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    dialogLayout.addView(scrollWrapper);
    dialogLayout.addView(buyButton);

    buyStockDialog.setView(dialogLayout);

    buyStockDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            int numInterations = STOCK_TO_PURCHASE.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < numInterations; i++) {
                STOCK_TO_PURCHASE.remove(0);
            }
        }
    });

    buyStockDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: is buyStockDialog an AlertDialog.Builder?

Comment: Could you include the declaration line for buyStockDialog.

Comment: added the declaration line

Comment: is this button is part of dialog layout? Can you provide your complete dialog showing method code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between AlertDialog, which has a dismiss() function. And AlertDialog.Builder which is the builder pattern for the alert dialog. When you are about to show the dialog you call

`buyStockDialog.create()`

The returned value there is the one you have to call dismiss on.

Comment: It was a valid effort but buyStockDialog.create().dismiss() doesn't work. It doesn't give me any errors but it also doesn't close the dialog.

Comment: That's because now you are creating a new dialog you never show and then dismissing that dialog. In the place where you display the dialog... the place where you already called buyStockDialog.create().show(). That is the object you need to pay attention to. buyStockDialog is just the builder. it is unimportant, you should not remember it or attempt to use it other than the first creation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this where you declare your dialog:

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme);
AlertDialog.Builder buyStockDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
buyStockDialog.setTitle("Buy Stock: ");
final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
```

And inside your click listener where you want to dismiss the dialog you will call this:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```